# Kill processes by name

Tags: 12.04, server, python

I have got python http server. OS - ubuntu server 12.04. Some time i need to kill all python http processes. I use this command

```
sudo killall python
```

But it kills all python processes. Is it possible to kill all processes with name 'python server.py'?

Comment: man killall will probably help you - the command is described there pretty well.

Comment: this [link][1] may have a solution for you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381229/how-to-kill-all-processes-matching-a-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pkill -f` instead:

```
pkill -f 'python server.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

`pkill -f 'python3 -m http.server 8000'` if one is using the `http.server` module in python3, and the default port

`pgrep -a python` will list all python and the individual names required to distinguish.